# Ambitous Summer study schedule - is it realistic

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

Since sometime early this year, I have been self-studying mathematics. Slowly, I have been making somewhat noticeable progress. My ultimate goal is to begin exploring subjects Topology and Geometry, but I do not think that I have sufficient prerequisites. This summer, I have much more free time to fill these gaps and thus, I plan isolate myself for about two hours each day completing exercises and working through books, books covering the three main subjects I wish to learn this Summer, namely Analysis, Linear Algebra, Abstract Algebra, and Calculus of Several Variables (curves, surfaces, manifolds, etc). Books I've considered reading include:

- For Analysis, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Rudin , most likely supplemented by one of the following (my favorite so far being Tao):

  1. *Analysis I* - Tao
  2. *Mathematical Analysis* - Apostol
  3. *Understanding Analysis* - Abbott
- For Linear Algebra, *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Axler. I read some of the first chapter and it looks awesome.
- For Algebra, *Elements of Abstract Algebra* by Clark. I love the problem-oriented nature of the book, plus it is very concise, unlike Dummit and Foote's tome.
- For Multivraiable Calculus and Differential Geometry, I have looked at

  1. *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* - Lee
  2. *Calculus on Manifolds* - Spivak
  3. *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* - do Carmo
  4. *A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms* - Bachman

In fact, I'd like to learn more, but five, possibly six books seems a little absurd. My basic goal is to get a solid undergraduate education myself this Summer. Mostly, by myself, that is. Luckily, I do have access to someone to check my work and solutions to exercises, so if I do not understand the theory and complete the exercises erroneously, at least I will know.

> Moreover, is my ambitious self-study plan realistic? Is it humanly possible for an enthusiast with sufficient mathematical maturity and background in proofs, namely me, to power through six books in one Summer? In my personal opinion, although I have merely previewed *most* of them, the books above are
>   thorough and readable (with the exception of Rudin; although thorough, it is not quite as readable as the other books, but for that reason I intend to supplement it with a more readable text, such as Tao). My only constraint is time - precisely, I am confined to three months. Considering that, how can I best allocate my time? Should I only do exercises from one book and read from another? Should I read two unrelated books at once or focus one subject at any particular time. With that, what is the most logical order in which to read the above books? Is there anything I could add to or remove from the above list to receive better a better foundation in *undergraduate* mathematics?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Since asking, I’ve picked up Tao and Rudin’s analysis texts to study this summer. I appreciate all of the comments and advice I have received. Also, my schedule has changed so that I can dedicate much more time, hopefully 5-6 hours a day.

**Edit 2:** Due to further comments, I’ve decided to read Terry Tao’s book *only*.

Comment: I think if you cut out multivariable calculus and differential geometry, you could just about do it in one summer. You'd need to be spending more like 4-5 hours per day, though, if you ask me. At least. It does depend on how thorough you want to be, e.g. what proportion of the exercises you intend to do. I suggest cutting MC and DG because the books you've listed are substantially harder and generally require more topology.

Comment: Personally I think it's unrealistic. Mastering the books by Abbot and Axler would be a big accomplishment already. Why the rush?

Comment: @AreaMan Oh, I just have no time during the year because I have to go back to school (I’m not at university yet).

Comment: @Mr.Chip If I threw a Topology book like Munkres in there and took out the MC and DG books, is that more reasonable?

Comment: Perhaps one of these books at most, given 1-2 hours a day. You'll find that some of the concepts take a long time to grasp, and much much more to master! Normally this list takes a full 4-year undergrad course to learn.

Comment: @majormaki Don't study munkres before you've learned some analysis.

Comment: @AreaMan Got it!

Comment: Based on personal experience, it can take a full summer to learn decently well the material in Abbots analysis. You will make much more progress if you focus on one thing, and think about it critically, and really try to internalize its key ideas.

Comment: just a comment, in my opinion there is a huge jump in difficulty from Abbot's book to Rudin's.

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit more about your background? What math courses have you taken? If you have never taken any analysis class before and unless you have Stephen Hawking's IQ, then 1 or 2 hours per day is not enough for Rudin's, or even Axler's. Even so, I believe Stephen Hawking had probably spent the whole day and each day contemplating physics.

Comment: Is this really an answer? I’m already satisfied with information I have received above, and I do not believe this is really adding anything. Honestly, you’re merely asking another question. I did not ask how many hours Stephen Hawking spent contemplating physics.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1018921)

Comment: Is it possible to lazily read through them 1-2 hours a day? Yes. Is it possible to master them all? No way. Mastering a book is not about reading, it's about doing the exercises and the proofs, and understanding how and when to apply the material. A single exercise could well take more that 2 hours. Anyway, if you are an enthousiast, I'd expect you spend at least 8 hours a day on this, unless you have another activity.

Comment: Also, if you have no previous experience of topology, you are going to suffer a lot with any book dealing with manifolds. Too much, too fast.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yeah, I learned that the hard way with John Lee’s book.

Comment: I would pick ONE of these.  Learning math can be very time consuming - it is not at all unusual to spend a full two hours reading through just a few pages, not even doing exercises.  It takes about as much time and discipline as learning a musical instrument.  Don't get discouraged, but also don't expect to play Rachmaninoff on your second day.

Comment: @JairTaylor Okay. I think I know which one I’ll pick.

Comment: I think you can choose 2 of these books to read in the summer. I don't know if you could finish reading them or if that's your goal but you can get a lot of mathematics from that!

Comment: Also, I'm an ambitous student like you and I've learned that sometimes focusing deeply on less things is much better. Focus on understanding and you'll do well. Best of studies!

Comment: @LeoLerena Thanks. I really appreciate it. Best of luck in your studies as well!